# how to check if a container has an button or image

Tags: cypress

Im testing a website and i want to know how to validate if a class contains any buttons or not or if a class or div has an image inside it

I tried this code

```js
cy.get('.banner-square-overlay-container').invoke('button').should('have.length.gt', 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

**Invoke** is for applying the function to the container.
To find a button in the container you need to use the **find** command.

Something like this:

```js
cy.get('.banner-square-overlay-container')
  .find('button')
  .should('have.length.gt', 0)
```